# Fixed Background not working on mobile

Tags: android, html, css

My wrapper is as follows:

```
#wrapper{
background:url(../images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
padding-top:80px;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}
```

this works perfectly on desktop and even resized desktop browsers below 480px but when i try to run this on an android phone, **it only shows like 10% of the background** and that scrolls with the page til other divs hide it. i need it to be fixed on the mobile screen and not move while im scrolling the content over it. `background-attachment:fixed` seems to be not supported by android for some reason. but there are websites that does it perfectly on mobile like [this one](http://wherewedream.org).

so i need this media query to be filled so it works on android too:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#wrapper{

}
}
```

Comment: If i understood the quesion right.this maybe because you have added the 'padding-top:80px' and the background image is fixed.so it doesnt work even when you scroll

Comment: @Shrikanth Buds it works on desktop, that padding is for the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the rest of you html and body css?  I have it on a site I did recently and used this. My html and body is 100% and the container is 90% so you can see the image around the container all the time

```css
html. body {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url(images/Exeter.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#036;
 }

#container {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff;    
 }
```

here is a live example http://myexeterhome.com/

Comment: wow i just tried adding `::after` next to body and `positon:fixed` to your code and it worked. switching the background image into body is a good idea. thanks a lot.